# Clone form fields and increment id as well

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc

I need to add the row and increment the id as well when click on add button. My code adds the rows accordingly but the `id` is not being increased.

When I'm inserting the data in the second row it is saved with the first id. I need to increase the id also as well as adding the row

html:

```
   <table id="mytable" class="noborder">
   <tbody>


   <tr>
    
   <td class="labelTextDetails">Dailyrep Id</td>
   <td class="labelTextDetails">Date</td>
   <td class="labelTextDetails">Task Type</td>
   <td class="labelTextDetails">Description</td>

    <td><input  type="text" /></td>
    <td><label onclick="add()">Add</label></td>

     </tr>

    <tr>
    <td class="fieldText"><s:input path="id" /> 
    </td>
   <td class="fieldText"><s:input path="date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" 
    /> 
   </td>
  <td class="fieldText"> <s:select  path="task_type" 
  class="dropdown_Free">
 <s:option value="" label="Select"/>
 <s:option value="Technical" label="Technical"/>
 <s:option value="Non-Technical" label="Non-Technical"/>
 </s:select></td>
 <td class="fieldText"><s:input path="description" /></td>
 </tbody></table>
```

javascript:

```
      function add(){
var row = $("#mytable > tbody > tr:last").html();
  $('#mytable > tbody').append('<tr>' + row + '</tr>');
  
  
}
```

Comment: What id are you talking about? There's only `mytable` and you're doing nothing with that o.O

Comment: Firstly, which `id`? There's only an `id` on the table itself, on the row. Secondly, use an unobtrusive JS event handler, not an inline `onclick` attribute. Thirdly, don't use incremental ids, set at runtime. It makes the code needlessly complex for no useful benefit. Use common classes, data attributes and/or DOM traversal to relate elements instead.

Comment: *I need to increase the id* - no, no you don't.  You might *think* you do, but you don't really - and when you realise that you'll find your problems are solved.   XY Problem - you think you need to increase id, but really you don't need an id at all.

Comment: There's a specialized tool for cloning nodes -> [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan : i have edited my question. when i'm inserting the data on second row  i have to increase the Dailyrep Id

Comment: @Andreas:  i have edited my question. when i'm inserting the data on second row i have to increase the Dailyrep Id

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
function add() {
  var row = $("#mytable > tbody > tr:nth-child(2)").html();
  $('#mytable > tbody').append('<tr>' + row + '</tr>');
  $.each($('.textbox'), function(index) {
    $(this).attr('value', index + 1);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" class="noborder">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="labelTextDetails">Dailyrep Id</td>
      <td class="labelTextDetails">Date</td>
      <td class="labelTextDetails">Task Type</td>
      <td class="labelTextDetails">Description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="fieldText">
        <input class="textbox" path="id" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="fieldText">
        <input path="date" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" />
      </td>
      <td class="fieldText">
        <select path="task_type" class="dropdown_Free">
          <option value="" label="Select" />
          <option value="Technical" label="Technical" />
          <option value="Non-Technical" label="Non-Technical" />
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="fieldText">
        <input path="description" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label onclick="add()">Add</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: On with line you like to increase the id? Post the code line.

Comment: i have edited my code...i have to increase the Dailyrep Id

Comment: I have updated my code example. Check it and if it fits your needs please upvote or check the post as answered. THX

Comment: but in sql the data is updated with first id only....when i'm inserting second row that data also go to with first id only in sql

Comment: actually in database the second row should update with id=2; but when ever i'm inserting the 2nd row the data is updated with id=1 in database

Comment: with your database insert statement I could not help you. My above script works properly. Checked the source code in Chrome Developer Tools and the value is increasing right. Maybe you have to increase every name attribute also e.g name="textbox-' + id + ' and so on. Otherwise you are using textbox several times and your script recognizes only the first row.